# How do I make an input text bar transparent but keep the text inside solid?

Tags: html, css, input, text, opacity

Is there a way to make an input text bar transparant but keep the text inside the bar a solid color?
The Problem im getting is that by setting the bars opacity, it also adjusts the texts opacity as well.

I need the text to be solid white or else it wont stand out from the input bar and the color of the header containing it.

HTML:

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/CSS/reset.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/CSS/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
       <header>
           <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Add an item"/>
           <button id="button"  type="button"><img src="./img/additem.png"></button>
        </header>
           <div id="list">


           </div>
        </div>
     <script src="resources/JS/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#input{
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  border:0;
  opacity:0.6;
  color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  text-indent: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
}
```

Comment: What is it you call "an input text bar"?

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to figured it out.
In case anyone else has this problem, I fixed it by using "background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);" to make only the Input bar transparent. Since the text isn't effected, you just set the text color normally using "color:".

CSS:

```
#input{
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  border:0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-indent: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
}
```